(Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))
I have a function that it requests to telegram and befor, it set a proxy socks5. whene it requests, an exception is raised.
code:
        def get_request_page(self, base_url: str = "https://t.me/", proxy_url=None):
            url = base_url + str(self.channel.username)
            if proxy_url is not None:
                proxy_info = {
                    "http": proxy_url,
                    "https": proxy_url
                }
                response = requests.get(url=url, proxies=proxy_info, verify=certifi_location)

            else:
                response = requests.get(url=url, verify=certifi_location)
            if response.status_code // 100 != 2:
                return ""

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

            return soup.get_text()

error:  SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='t.me', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /solitude_comp_music (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))
what should I do?

Make sure that it works with this specific proxy outside of Python. While it is unclear what proxy you use many public "free" proxies do not support HTTPS urls.

I encountered the same issue with requests. After some extensive troubleshooting, I discovered that it was caused by using a higher version of urllib3.
Error-inducing versions:
requests           2.31.0
urllib3            2.2.1

Resolved versions:
requests           2.31.0
urllib3            1.26.18


Remember to ensure compatibility between requests and urllib3 versions. If you need to downgrade urllib3, you can use the following pip command:
pip install urllib3==1.26.18

Finally, test your requests again to ensure the issue has been resolved.
